# Absolutely dead confused about what is going in this code and problem. Can someone explain to me where to even begin?

Tags: java, visual-studio

I have to apply linear scan to this problem, and I just don't even know where to start. I feel as if I should change my career path honestly, this is a simple intro problem and i'm just not understanding anything about it.

```
/**
 * Applies the linear scan strategy to counting the number of negative
 * values in an array.
 */
public class CountNegatives {

    /**
     * Returns the number of negative values in the given array.
     */
    public static int countNegatives(int[]a) {
        neg=0;
        for{i=0;i<a.length;i++}
            if(i>0)
                neg = neg+1;
        return neg;
        
    }
}
```

I've tried running this in VS and a tool my school uses called JGrasp. Both told me the { should be ( , the ; between length and i should be > , i<a.length is not a statement, and that } should be ;

When I change any of these things, it tells me variable neg=0 cannot be found and doubles the amount of errors in the code.

Comment: Typo?  Your `for` loop syntax is broken.  It should be using parentheses, not curly braces.  (Just like the `if` syntax does).  You also never declare the variable `i`.  Or the variable `neg`.

Comment: yes, the `for` loop should be `for( ... )`, not curly brackets. Also, in Java, you can't use a variable before it has been *declared*, and `neg=0` is attempting to assign the value of zero to an undeclared variable. Changing it to `int neg=0` will help. That should get you a bit further.

Comment: If you change `for{i=0;i<a.length;i++}` to `for(i=0;i<a.length;i++)` is the issue resolved? i.e. a for statement uses parantheses and not braces.

Comment: Also, don't give up! Success in programming, like any activity, is about grit - this is part of the learning process. We've all been there :-)

Answer (score 2):

There are a few things you missed,

1. You did not initialize the `neg=0;` value with the proper data type; you should initialize it with the proper data type, which int his case is `int`, correct initialization would be `int neg = 0;`
2. the other problem would be in the for loop you still need to initialize `i` with a data type
3. the if statement is wrong, it should be 'i<0' instead cause with your code you are just counting the positive values
4. You are comparing the index value with 0 so you won't get the right value, instead, you should compare the value in the array that corresponds to that index, you can do this by  `arrayName[index]`.

The correct code would be as follows:

```
static int countNegatives(int[] a) {
        
        int neg = 0;
        
        for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            if(a[i] < 0) neg++;
            // this will just work as neg = neg +1;
        }
        
        return neg;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public class CountNegatives {
/**
 * Returns the number of negative values in the given array.
 */
public static int countNegatives(int[]a) {
        int neg=0;
        for(int number : a){
            if(number<0) {
                neg=neg+1;
            }
        }
        return neg;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is good - you may want to consider using a for-loop similar to the one that the OP uses for them to understand the difference. Your version could be included as a comment outlining an alternative